# Dropbear SSH server is claiming the Debian user is locked (when it's not?)

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, user-accounts, dropbear

Having problem logging into a Debian (stable-slim) docker trough SSH.

Dropbear is started *(using supervisord or manually)* with:

```
dropbear -E -B -m -F -p 2222 -r /home/warbandserver/.config/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -c '/home/warbandserver/.ssh_login.sh'
```

And appears to be running fine, *(and is being ran by the same user attempting to login trough ssh.)*

But, upon trying to ssh into the dropbear , dropbear will complain

> *User account 'warbandserver' is locked*

But having checked, i can't for the life of me see how the account would be locked..

> sudo passwd --status warbandserver

returns:

> warbandserver P 08/02/2020 0 99999 7 -1

> sudo grep warbandserver /etc/shadow

returns:

> warbandserver:$6$0vNqyM8xCqRk7h14$rAigJ1hWzib0eWA4XTwjCwi.YouWuAPbdyeZLfdlGZqCVJ3zVg2tKyxkhHlzd/pjlccwLB.K9JCqSzu0rIsja.:18476:0:99999:7:::

This problem happens with both the debian packaged version and with build of the latest dropbear from github sources.

Could it perhaps be related to this *(passwd / shadow)* problem: https://serverfault.com/a/952633 , even though the error message differs?

Some notable links:

- https://www.2daygeek.com/lock-unlock-disable-enable-user-account-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is indeed related to **/etc/shadow** , and not actually a case of the user account being locked or disabled..

Since i've yet to find a better solution for Debian than when i encountered the [similar problem on Alpine](https://serverfault.com/a/952633). It seems the best way to fix this is (again) to add the user running Dropbear to the group **'shadow'**

> *If the server is run as non-root, you most likely won't be able to
> allocate a pty, and you cannot login as any user other than that
> running the daemon (obviously). **Shadow passwords will also be unusable
> as non-root**.*
>
> *(ref: https://github.com/mkj/dropbear)*

*(Note: This work-around is probably not ideal where high security is top priority)*